# svn checkout without tags

Tags: ubuntu, subversion

How to checkout the repository without tags in svn.

Created tags in repository. Now whenever client users do svn checkout that tags also downloaded. So I need to svn checkout the repository without tags. How we can do that ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: within a single command I need to do svn checkout without tags

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the layout of your repository on the server.

If your layout is in the recommended format (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout) then the "tags" directory will be separate from the "trunk" directory (trunk being where new code is committed).

Then performing a checkout on the "trunk" directory will ignore "tags" since it's not a child of "trunk".

You can normally browse the repository on the server and move directories around to get the recommended layout (using something like TortoiseSVN on Windows). There isn't a special command to ignore subdirectories on a checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `-set-depth=exclude`. See https://blog.coffeebeans.at/archives/288. F.e.:

```
svn update --set-depth=exclude <foldername>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580501/checkout-a-complete-subversion-tree-excluding-tags-and-branches/58117811#58117811 for details